Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly hangs and freezes, and has to be restarted
I want to ask I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04 and sometimes it is annoying like suddenly hank, the mouse doesn't work, the audio doesn't work, and have to restart it to return to normal.
Does anyone know what problem with the hardware or software occurred, or what should I do so that this doesn't happen again?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

FYI:  You mention server which is usually used headless, but can also be used via text terminal. Ubuntu Server doesn't use a mouse as that is a desktop user interface. When 18.04 reached EOSS last year, I assume you read the EOSS/ESM notices & replaced the no-longer supported deb packages with the snap packages as was required for Desktop systems I assume; as if you didn't - you left parts of your system vulnerable  (this is more significant with Desktop systems - and you mention a mouse which Server doesn't use). Either way refer EOSS/ESM docs & seek Canonical support.
